# Azure Functions last run time

Tags: azure-functions

I have built an Azure Function that gets logs from one cloud application.  The API to retrieve the logs can only return one day at a time, so you need to pass the daystart and dayend.

I need to store the last successful run time of the function, to know from which range should I start when the function runs again: if it succeeds the next run will be only one day, if it fails (or wasn't triggered for any reason) it would loop at the number of days until today and retrieve all the logs.

Where can I store this value "LastSuccessfulRun" and how do I retrieve it?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

For a solution like this, I would recommend you to use table storage to store this information. simply update the "LastSuccessfulExecution" once that event happens, and use that data as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send the message to a queue or a file by using Integration section in Azure function as below:
You can use Azure Blob Storage, Azure Service Bus, Azure Table Storage.

Azure Blob Storage:

[image]

Azure Service Bus:

[image]

Then now you use your code to send data to service bus queue or storage account, [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74195249/how-to-write-to-blob-storage-as-output-binding-using-azure-function-with-service/74206167#74206167) for doing this.