# How to send messages to azure service bus using azure functions Http Trigger Python

Tags: azure-functions

I try to write messages service bus using the example in the documentation but don't write in my queue at azure service bus

this is a example for mi init.py

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, msg: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:

    input_msg = req.params.get('message')

    msg.set(input_msg)

    return "OK"
```

and this is the function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "admin",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "type": "serviceBus",
      "direction": "out",
      "connection": "my connection string in serviceBus",
      "name": "msg",
      "queueName": "name of queau in serviceBus"
    }
  ]
}
```

I expecting to write the messaje in the queau

Comment: (I see two occurrences of "queau". Can you put a spelling checker for English to good use?)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and I was getting 500 Internal Error. So I tried to do that in azure Databricks as an Alternative to use Python Language.

Firstly, I have installed packages as below and executed below code:

```
%pip install azure-functions
```

[image]

Then executed below code:

```
%pip install azure-servicebus==7.0.0
```

[image]

Then I have used below code to send message to service bus and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues)  :

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage

CONNECTION_STR="Endpoint=sb://rithk.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=+1UW3M="
QUEUE_NAME = "out"
message = ServiceBusMessage("Rithwik says Happy New Year")
servicebus_client=ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR,logging_enable=True)
with servicebus_client:
    servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME).send_messages(message)
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

You can also use C# language [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74195249/how-to-write-to-blob-storage-as-output-binding-using-azure-function-with-service/74206167#74206167)